# Amount of disk space needed to install

Tags: installation, dual-boot, disk-usage

I'd like to create a partition where to install Ubuntu in a Dell inspiron 6000 with WinXp OS already installed. What is the minimal amount of disk space required for booting the system? Then I'd create another partition for the data.

I tried to install Ubuntu alongside WinXP without creating a dedicated partition but the grub install failed at the end.

Answer (score 0):

> 5 GB of hard-drive space (or USB stick, memory card or external drive
>   but see LiveCD for an alternative approach)

You can find information about system requirements [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements).

For your grub problem, you are going to have to give some more details.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep a minimum of 6GB of disk space for the partition containing your Ubuntu but I would suggest giving that drive 10-15 GB of space for installing other things and updates for Ubuntu.

And yeah, installing Ubuntu alongside without a dedicated partition would not be a good idea,you should have seperate partitions for the different OS (and your data if possible).